# Android Read recent SMS messages from command line

Tags: sms, adb, command-line, broken-screen, sqlite

I have recently broken my Android's screen. (Again)

Its a T-Mobile G2

Trying to keep up with my busy technology related life is hard enough without losing my link with everyone.

I have rooted the phone and have the USB Debugging already turned on.

Does anyone know how I would check my recent SMS Messaged from the adb shell so I can keep up with work while i save up to get a new phone or a replacement screen.

Thanks for anyone that has any information regarding this.

## EDIT

Response to eldarerathis

```
C:\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
$ cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
$ sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3: permission denied
$
```

cant chmod the file.
do you know actually where it is ?

```
$ chmod +x sqlite3
chmod +x sqlite3
Bad mode
$
```

su leaves me with only basic commands

```
$ su
su
# cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
# sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3: not found
#
```

## Corrected

sqlite was not installed

```
C:\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
$ cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
$ sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3 mmssms.db
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite>
```

Also to Access the database I needed to be root.

```
C:\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
$ su
# cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
cd /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
# sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3 mmssms.db
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite>
```

Thanks a lot eldarerathis

[This Link Helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-ope)

Comment: It looks like you don't have the `sqlite3` binary on your device. The first link in my answer has instructions to help you install it to `/system/bin`. [Here is a link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16958605/sqlite3) to the binary itself.

Comment: I know this is 10 years old, but if you're looking for a cleaner answer, look here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241439/how-to-access-texts-on-rooted-android-device-from-terminal/241440#241440. Might need to modify the script slightly to get new messages as opposed to messages based on conversation name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is really ugly, but you can read them from the command line by using `sqlite3` to view the database entries. You'll probably need to dig up a binary for this unless you have a custom ROM installed. There are some instructions for installing said binary in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645319/why-do-i-get-a-sqlite3-not-found-error-on-a-rooted-nexus-one-when-i-try-to-ope), and [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) comes packaged with it (a copy of the binary itself can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16958605/sqlite3)).

If you do need to install the binary, use `mount` (with no parameters) to determine where your `/system` partition is physically located (mine is `/dev/block/mtdblock3`, for example). Then follow the instructions in the first link above, and start by remounting it in read/write mode with the command:

```
mount -o rw,remount /your/system/partition /system
```

Once you have `sqlite3` you'll want to open an `adb shell`, switch to root with `su`, and then do the following:

```
# cd /data/data
cd /data/data
# cd com.android.providers.telephony/databases ***
cd com.android.providers.telephony/databases
# sqlite3 mmssms.db
sqlite3 mmssms.db
SQLite version 3.7.2
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM sms WHERE read=0;
```

This will pull up all of the rows from the table for all of the unread messages. The columns in the table are defined thusly (so you can trim the `SELECT`):

```
CREATE TABLE sms (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,thread_id INTEGER,address TEXT,
  person INTEGER,date INTEGER,protocol INTEGER,read INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  status INTEGER DEFAULT -1,type INTEGER,reply_path_present INTEGER,
  subject TEXT,body TEXT,service_center TEXT,locked INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
  error_code INTEGER DEFAULT 0,seen INTEGER DEFAULT 0);
```

***Note for the marked line: this may be slightly different depending on your device and version of Android which is why I have included this `cd` command separately. I *think* it used to be `com.android.providers/telephony/databases` on older devices but I don't quite remember. Use `ls` to look around for the proper pathing here.

---

Alternatively, you could try copying the .db file onto your SD card (or pulling it with `adb pull`) and then reading it on your computer with sqlite.

Comment: I tried this and it seems that sqlite3 has permission denied

Comment: it says bad mode

Comment: @Jason: You need to be root to read that directory (just execute `su` beforehand).

Comment: @Jason: Hm, use `chmod 0755 sqlite3`, then. Maybe the stock `chmod` binary doesn't like the `+x` parameter.

Comment: as soon as I execute su. it acts like there are no commands

Comment: ok. thats a better mode. but I have to find sqlite. ill see if I can find it

Comment: @Jason: Most likely `/system/bin` if it's already installed, otherwise you can put it in `/system/bin` yourself.

Comment: yes you are correct. sqlite3 was not installed. Thank goodness for adb and su. And thanks a lot eldarerathis. adding sqlite3 to my /system/bin folder solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the beautiful hint above from eldarerathis, I just do

```
DB=/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
echo 'select address,body from sms;' | ./sqlite3 -csv $DB
```

to read my SMSes from my root prompt.

Since I didn't have sqlite3, I first had to [download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16958605/sqlite3) it with

```
curl http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16958605/sqlite3
chmod a+x sqlite3
```

Or see [SQLite3 installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ptSoft.util.sqlite3forroot&hl=de) on Google Play (if you don't trust the dropbox source).

Comment: A dl.dropbox.com URL for that binary doesn't feel safe. Can you supply an official source?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested in more details than just sender and message (as in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/32413/16575)), I've just found a nice article on the topic: [Read SMS directly from Sqlite database in Android](https://cmanios.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/read-sms-directly-from-sqlite-database-in-android/). Also see: [The message data structure](http://www.programering.com/a/MzNzkjNwATQ.html).

Even better, take a look at Github: **[ANDROID-SMS](https://github.com/muri11as/ANDROID-SMS)** is a tool written in Python which *recovers all SMS messages and organizes them into SMS Conversations with statistics provided.* It *also recovers all MMS messages and organizes them into MMS Conversations,
with the respective files.* I've not tried it (yet) myself (just found it a few minutes ago), but it sounds pretty neat.

Of course, this program doesn't work on the Android device directly – but instead on your computer (where it requires Python 2.7 with SQLite3 for Python). So you will need to first pull the database from the device. All required steps are described on the project's Github main page.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I invented utilizes an app on the phone that reacts on SMS and saves it to a file that you can read with ADB.

- Install any Tasker-like app, I made it with E-Robot
- Create new command
- Add event `Contact=>SMS`
- Add action `Memory=>Write file`, there you can save SMS to a new file every time or to the same one with separator. Anyway save it to /sdcard or any path accessible via ADB.
- Monitor that path with ADB and read SMS contents.