# How to access texts on rooted Android device from terminal

Tags: root-access, sms, privacy, terminal, data-transfer

How do I access text messages on my rooted device using the command line?

I specifically want to extract a text transcript, without using any cloud services and thereby exposing sensitive or personal info.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215426/218526

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requirements:

1. Linux terminal (may work on other systems; untested).
2. `adb` installed.
3. "USB Debugging" enabled.
4. Rooted Android device (may work on unrooted; untested).

Sequence:

1. Plug in device.
2. Put device in "File Transfer" mode.
3. Start session with root access: `adb root`.
4. Accept prompt on device to allow USB debugging.
5. Start interactive shell at root dir (`/`): `adb shell`.
6. Locate database file using `ls`, `find`, and whatever tools you see fit. Mine was: `/data/data/com.android.messaging/databases/bugle_db`.
7. Exit the shell with `exit` or `Ctrl-d`.
8. Pull the file onto your local machine: `adb pull <file> ~/texts.db`.
9. Run [this script](https://github.com/mcp292/extract-convo-from-textdb) to extract messages: `python3 extract_convo_from_textdb.py ~/texts.db "<convo-name>"`.